# computing spectrograms of wav files & recorded sound (normalizing for volume)

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, fft

I want to compare recorded audio with audio read from disk in a consistent way, but I'm running into problems with normalization for volume (otherwise amplitudes of spectrograms are different).

I also have never worked with signals, FFTs, or the WAV format ever before so this is new, uncharted territory for me. I retrieve channels as lists of signed 16bit ints sampled at 44100 Hz from both

1. on disk .wav files
2. recorded music playing from my laptop

and then I proceed through each with a window (2^k) with a certain amount of overlap. For each window like so:

```
# calculate window variables
window_step_size = int(self.window_size * (1.0 - self.window_overlap_ratio)) + 1
last_frame = nframes - window_step_size # nframes is total number of frames from audio source
num_windows, i = 0, 0 # calculate number of windows
while i <= last_frame: 
    num_windows += 1
    i += window_step_size

# allocate memory and initialize counter
wi = 0 # index
nfft = 2 ** self.nextpowof2(self.window_size) # size of FFT in 2^k
fft2D = np.zeros((nfft/2 + 1, num_windows), dtype='c16') # 2d array for storing results

# for each window
count = 0
times = np.zeros((1, num_windows)) # num_windows was calculated

while wi <= last_frame:

    # channel_samples is simply list of signed ints
    window_samples = channel_samples[ wi : (wi + self.window_size)]
    window_samples = np.hamming(len(window_samples)) * window_samples 

    # calculate and reformat [[[[ THIS IS WHERE I'M UNSURE ]]]]
    fft = 2 * np.fft.rfft(window_samples, n=nfft) / nfft
    fft[0] = 0 # apparently these are completely real and should not be used
    fft[nfft/2] = 0 
    fft = np.sqrt(np.square(fft) / np.mean(fft)) # use RMS of data
    fft2D[:, count] = 10 * np.log10(np.absolute(fft))

    # sec / frame * frames = secs
    # get midpt
    times[0, count] = self.dt * wi

    wi += window_step_size
    count += 1

# remove NaNs, infs
whereAreNaNs = np.isnan(fft2D);
fft2D[whereAreNaNs] = 0;
whereAreInfs = np.isinf(fft2D);
fft2D[whereAreInfs] = 0;

# find the spectorgram peaks
fft2D = fft2D.astype(np.float32)

# the get_2D_peaks() method discretizes the fft2D periodogram array and then
# finds peaks and filters out those peaks below the threshold supplied
# 
# the `amp_xxxx` variables are used for discretizing amplitude and the 
# times array above is used to discretize the time into buckets
local_maxima = self.get_2D_peaks(fft2D, self.amp_threshold, self.amp_max, self.amp_min, self.amp_step_size, times, self.dt)
```

In particular, the crazy stuff (to me at least) happens on the line with my comment [[[[ THIS IS WHERE I'M UNSURE ]]]].

Can anyone point me in the right direction or help me to generate this audio spectrogram while normalizing for volume correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look tells me that you forgot to use a window, it is necessary to calculate your Spectrogram .

You need to use one Window (hamming, hann)  in your "window_samples"

`np.hamming(len(window_samples)) * window_samples`

Then you can calculate rfft.

**Edit:**

```
#calc magnetitude from FFT
fftData=fft(windowed);
#Get Magnitude (linear scale) of first half values
Mag=abs(fftData(1:Chunk/2))
#if you want log scale R=20 * np.log10(Mag)
plot(Mag)
```

> #calc RMS from FFT
>   RMS = np.sqrt( (np.sum(np.abs(np.fft(data)**2) / len(data))) / (len(data) / 2) )
>
> RMStoDb = 20 * log10(RMS)

PS: If you want calculate RMS from FFT you cant use Window(Hann, Hamming), this line makes no sense:

```
fft = np.sqrt(np.square(fft) / np.mean(fft)) # use RMS of data
```

One simple normalization data can be done for each window:

```
window_samples = channel_samples[ wi : (wi + self.window_size)]

#framMax=np.max(window_samples);
framMean=np.mean(window_samples);

Normalized=window_samples/framMean;
```

Comment: I mean that's good practice to use a scaling of the values in the window, but I don't think it's fundamentally wrong without it. However, I did add your suggestion. A follow up: Should I have negative amplitudes? For instance, taking all the amplitudes from the 2D spectrogram array (`fft2D` in my code above), I get: http://i.imgur.com/gLyi3OW.png

Comment: to clarify, that's a histogram of amplitude values

Comment: for Linear amplitude you can get abs values from first half values of your FFT - See Update !

Comment: but I want to normalize for volume - wouldn't I have to divide the spectrogram by the sum of all the amplitudes after doing FFT to truly be agnostic of the volume of the song?

Comment: The easy way is normalize the volume in time domain and then apply FFT, how you show us is not the best way to do !